# How to make Interaction with GWT - Spring RestTemplate

Tags: spring, gwt, resttemplate, gwt-compiler

This is the continuation of [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12972409/1012454)

I'm currently working on a task where it has `GWT`, `Restful` and `Spring Framework` environment.

It has two application; **Application #1** which expose some information through Restful Webservice and **Application #2** which consume that service and display those details in GWT.

For Application #2, I have used `Spring RestTemplate` to consume the `Restful Webservice` and return backs the List of Details through an Interface. And at the GWT end, there was some `DataListProvider` to set the Data List in `GWT-DataGrid`.

Now the problem is, I doesn't know how to make the interaction with `GWT DataListProvider` with my `DetailService` Class(this returns the **`List<Details>`** in a method). When I directly call the Service Class in `GWT- OnModule()` method, during `GWT Compile`, i'm facing some **UnResolved Type Error**, Since this class indirectly calls the `Spring Libraries` classes, thus GWT cannot compile this.

```
com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Failed to get JNode
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.TypeMap.get(TypeMap.java:140)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.TypeMap.get(TypeMap.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.getType(BuildTypeMap.java:730)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.createField(BuildTypeMap.java:570)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.access$300(BuildTypeMap.java:99)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap$BuildDeclMapVisitor.visit(BuildTypeMap.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.FieldDeclaration.traverse(FieldDeclaration.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.traverse(TypeDeclaration.java:1232)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.traverse(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:687)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.createPeersForNonTypeDecls(BuildTypeMap.java:637)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.exec(BuildTypeMap.java:514)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.exec(BuildTypeMap.java:523)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:599)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:33)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:284)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:233)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:145)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:232)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:198)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:170)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:88)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:82)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:177)
      [ERROR] <no source info>: public class org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate
    extends org.springframework.http.client.support.InterceptingHttpAccessor
    implements : Unresolved type org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations
```

Please provide your suggestion how to make an interaction between these Service Class and GWT.

Comment: Please provide some source code/config and a stack trace for us.

Comment: @AndersRostgaardBystrup: added those details in POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have Spring in client side code.

Options available are:

A callback in a presenter where an asynchronous interface makes a GWT-RPC call to a service controller (on server-side of App#2). You could have an @RequestMapping annotated method whose internals employ the RestTemplate.

Have the presenter employ a RequestFactory and make use of GWT overlay feature for your payload.